# Vercel deploy -> NestJs - ERROR Cannot find module 'src/..'

Tags: node.js, nestjs, vercel

I have this problem when I try to deploy an backend with nestjs in vercel platform.I have a repository on GitHub with two paths, client and api, and I have deployed the client with angular and all is good, but when I try it with the backend, I think that the error is in vercel.json

My directory schema

```
client
 -src
 -package.json
 -...<angular files>
api
 -src
 -tsconfig.json
 -vercel.json <--
```

vercel.json

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "src/main.ts",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "destination": "src/main.ts"
    }
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "paths": {
      "src": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried change this files but anything solved this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be months late but since I got the same problem, maybe it can help anyone gets here.

The solution (for now, at least) is to replace all your imports with relative paths, like so :

from -> `import { UsersService } from 'src/users/users.service';`

to ----> `import { UsersService } from '../users/users.service';`

(source : https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/2323)